# Erlang not using all cores of cpu when running concurrent tasks, why?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, erlang

Currently, I am reading a "Programming Erlang" book and I decided to test my system in a benchmark which creates N number of processes, here is the code:

```
-module(my_ring).
-export([start/1, start_proc/2]).

start(Num) ->
    start_proc(Num, self()).

start_proc(0, Pid) ->
    Pid ! ok;
start_proc(Num, Pid) ->
    NPid = spawn(?MODULE, start_proc, [Num - 1, Pid]),
    NPid ! ok,
    receive
        ok ->
            ok
    end.
```

I have Intel i5 on Windows 7 x64 and, while creating 100 000 000 of processes, I checked load of my CPU. It turned out that only one core works at full capacity, others do nothing (so overall system load is 25%). I thought that Erlang VM would balance the load across all of 4 avaible cores, but it doesn't.

Does anybody know why? Is there anything bad with configurations of my Erlang VM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that one thing which limits the parallelism of this example is that there is actually very little parallel work being done. Each process spawns the next process in the chain and *immediately* sends it an `ok` message. This means that next process after having spawned its next process will receive an `ok` and terminate. So, in fact, there won't be many processes actually running concurrently.

One way you can see this is that you are starting 100M processes while the default system only allows ~34k processes *at the same time*.

A better test would be to start a ring processes where each one spawns the next process and goes into loop where it receives a message and sends it to the next process. You would then have the whole ring running at the same time. To get the proper parallel activity the head of the ring would have to send a large number of messages around the ring **before** it starts receiving them out of the ring. If you sent **one** message at a time around the ring there would still only be one process at a time doing work.

Having a lot of processes is no guarantee for parallelism in your application, see [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) for a description of the problem.

Comment: I don't think it will terminate the process on receive because there is no timeout specified, it will just spawn all those processes and they all will wait for messages, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Troydm they will terminate. Each process runs the function `start_proc/2` which spawns the next process, immediately sends it an `ok` and then waits till it receives an `ok` after which it terminates. It will receive the `ok` very quickly as the process which spawned it has sent it immediately. So there will be very few processes running in parallel as they all terminate quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's still quite difficult to grasp that concurrency thing in Erlang but I'm going to try :)